# Comparing MySQL to Timescale on PostgreSQL, to store a table called Stocks for around 2000 tickers, what would be a better choice?

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql

So I compared storage and performance of both MySQL and Timescaledb on PostgreSQL. I'm uploading 100's of CSV files to the stock data table using a python script (uploading using python multiprocessing)

For MySQL I had to create the distributions myself: I created schemas y2008,y2009,...up-to y2020. Within each schema I created 10 tables (a_c, d_f, ..etc to store the tickers in alphabetical groups for best insert and query performance).

For TimescaleDB, I simply had to create_hypertable(stocks,..) which distributed the data into chunks/tables by the Date column. I did not have to 'manually' create the schemas and distributions as in MySQL.

Currently I've tested both setups for 100 tickers, around 6 GB of data. Timescaledb gave a better insert performance (5-6 minutes) as opposed to MySQL (9-10 minutes).

Also, these comparisons are for local PC setups. I haven't compared for even larger data set's or cloud database performances yet.

If someone has experience storing such time-series data, please let me know what is your opinion on the two, or if you recommend something else to look into as well.

Thanks a lot

Comment: *for best insert and query performance* ?!?! You seem very certain of this

Comment: https://github.com/akankshaialpha/mysql-stock-data My data has a fixed size, which I tested for various distribution sizes. I also know how large each schema will be by the end of the year and then no further inserts - [for 1 stock, 262 days of data, with 390 data-points per day: 930am-4pm=390 points].  If you see how I have equally distributed the stocks with the help of the Populate_Ticker_Dir.py script it might be clearer. The repository also has a report pdf file to understand in detail.

Comment: And you never query across tables/schemas?

Comment: So to be clearer, I meant best insert and query performance customized for my case, and from all the distributions I tried. But yes, please let me know if you have any suggestions how to improve my architecture further :)

Comment: Well, you seem to know best - but if it was me, I'd at least be curious to know how this compared with just sticking everything in one (properly indexed) table (in MySQL).

Comment: Yes I am querying too. I'm going by a two step plan. First, best possible insert performance and then query performance. I'm still in the very initial phase

Comment: Presumably, INSERTs (for historical data) only happen once?

Comment: Yes I tried having just one table in MySQL too. But InnoDB engine has a restriction on table sizes, so my mysql connection and thus inserts broke

Comment: Yes INSERTS only once. And no updates. Pure time-series data and architecture